# Device keeps crashing with 100% CPU usage

Tags: linux, cpu, freeze, crash, cpu-usage

From time to time my Laptop freezes and is unusable with 100% CPU usage on at least 1 core.
I left btop open but the freeze seemed to be happening too quick as the process with the highest processor usage got 10% and all the other stuff was negligible.

I provided logs below, it is quite hard for me to interpret if there is any valid info in it.

[journalctl -b-2](https://privatebin.net/?b210d2c32e907927#FcQ72tBPJ3rPdLqC5RW4usi4LhCUAhJoseWN3UuPRqng)

[journalctl -b-2 -e -x](https://privatebin.net/?3f4f216589a6c219#E8HP8k3xW7EqpUBSC9yy9NM98yejX9j5syspuPGVccDc)

[journalctl -b -2 --no-tail](https://privatebin.net/?d7f6a0aef4804d6b#CTGLhuUYuKQxAToeKJncPv2XAAR3rUBvnrRHT1qxRsmg)

Edit: It just crashed again, so [here's](https://privatebin.net/?c52552321b5a5504#EjkEzjwzXq2Zp43Z34DNmH2DPtwbrVvLQiMWCRHoWLqr) another one with the --no-tail option

- OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64
- Host: ThinkPad T570
- Kernel: 6.1.0-18-amd64
- DE: Plasma 5.27.5
- WM: KWin
- CPU: Intel i5-7200U (4) @ 3.100GHz
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics 620
- Memory: 2734MiB / 7672MiB

Comment: So, what does `top/htop` report? 100% CPU use is always caused by some process, it can't be nothing even in Windows (where there's a `System` process which is the NT kernel). This might be an OOM storm but I'm not sure. `top` and `free` output is highly desired. Lastly what do you mean by "keeps crashing"? Does it freeze? Does it reboot on its own? What exactly happens?

Comment: Cannot provide the reports just now as I am not at home. All I can say for now is that I took a photo of btop when one of the most recent crashes occured and there was nothing too shady. One process using 10%  CPU, some others with 0,X%...Gonna provide top-report tomorrow.
With "keeps freezing"I mean that it freezes, I shut the device down via power button, start it again, keep doing regular stuff and it freezes again. Sometimes after 1 Minute, sometimes after 3 hours, it really is hard to pinpoint.

Comment: So the laptop just crashed again, here is the top report https://privatebin.net/?5d6399f242836423#HYK67wSXnJoVptXngx9W28nW4h31B3N8vj4vN1LmBCvF

Comment: Also here is a photo I took of psensor when the last crash occured: https://ibb.co/6yZNLwf

Comment: You've got enough RAM which means it's either a driver/kernel crash or some HW issue. I'd start with running memtest86/memtest86+ for an hour. If it comes clean, you could try installing kernel 6.7.6 and checking if it works.

Comment: I went with the Lenovo Utility to check every component (besides keyboard, touchpad, etc), not too promising... https://ibb.co/8jCrR3m